# Firebase database integration with gemini

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-gemini

Came across this article today on integration of firebase with Gemini. https://firebase.blog/posts/2024/02/supercharge-apps-firebase-gemini

Document mentions about

> Firebase Extensions are pre-packaged solutions that allow you to add
> new features to your apps with only a few lines of code. Both the
> Build Chatbot with the Gemini API and Multimodal Tasks with the Gemini
> API Firebase Extensions allow you to implement AI use cases by just
> writing documents to **Firestore**.

Q1. Is there alternative extension available that will help to integrate with firebase realtime database (not firestore)

Q2. If answer is YES, firebase realtime database is encrypted, is there way to train it with Customer-managed encryption keys hosted on google cloud directly?

Q3. Can plugin works with firebase security rules ( for data training, exclude data which is protected and only include one which is public )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q1. Is there an alternative extension available that will help to integrate with the Firebase Realtime Database (not Firestore)

No. As mentioned in the blog post, currently, there are only two extensions available, [Build Chatbot with the Gemini API](https://extensions.dev/extensions/googlecloud/firestore-genai-chatbot) and [Multimodal Tasks with the Gemini API](https://extensions.dev/extensions/googlecloud/firestore-multimodal-genai), and both work with Firestore.

> Q2. If the answer is YES, the Firebase Realtime Database is encrypted, is there a way to train it with Customer-managed encryption keys hosted on Google Cloud directly?

The answer was, unfortunately, no. However, if you need such an extension, you can create it yourself. In this way, you and other Firebase developers can benefit from it.

> Q3. Can the plugin work with Firebase Security Rules ( for data training, exclude data that is protected and only include one that is public)?

No. Firebase Extensions work with [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions), which means that each invocation will bypass the security rules entirely.

Comment: Thank you so much your reply. 3rd bullet of bypassing security rules is concerning?

Comment: Not at all, because the functions are called from a trusted environment.